# angularJS error with ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, ionic-framework, ng-options

I'm developing an app that received from a server a JSON array and than divided it in days (3) and times. Than in the html file there are two selects that should are populated with the days (the first select) and with the times "belonging" at the day choose in the first select (in the second select).
I've wrote a portion of code that are execute correctly but the two selects are empty.

This is my code,

**CONTROLLER.JS**:

```
ionicApp.controller('DefaultController', DefaultController)
  .factory('dataService', dataService);
DefaultController.$inject = ['dataService', '$http'];

function DefaultController(dataService, $http) {
  var vm = this;
  console.log("Dentro ctrl");
  getEvents();

  function getEvents() {
      console.log("Dentro getEvents");
    return dataService.getEvents()
      .then(function (data) {
          console.log(data);
        vm.data = data;
        console.log(vm.data);
        return vm.data;
      });
  }
    vm.submit = function (){
        console.log("funzione");
        console.log(vm.form);
        var data = vm.form; // IMPORTANT
        //console.clear();
        var link = 'http://localhost/ShuttleFIX/api/apiDoFix.php';
        var mail = window.localStorage.getItem("mail");
        var scelta = window.localStorage.getItem("scelta");
        console.log(data);
        $http.post(link, {giorno: data.giorno, ora: data.ora, mail: mail, scelta: scelta})
            .then(function (res){
                console.log("Dentro http.post");
                var response = res.data;
                if (response != 'F'){
                    console.log("Dentro if");
                    console.log(response);
                    window.location.href ="/main.html";
                } else {
                    console.log("Dentro else");
                }
            });
    };
}

dataService.$inject = ['$http'];

function dataService($http) {
    console.log("qua");
  var service = {
    getEvents: getEvents
  };

  return service;

  function getEvents() {
      console.log("qua2");
    var config = {
      transformResponse: function (data, headers) {
        var result = {
          events: [],
          schedules: []
        };
        var events = JSON.parse(data);
        var dates = [];
        console.log("qua3");
        for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
          if (dates.indexOf(events[i].day) === -1) {
            var date = events[i].day;
            dates.push(date);
            result.events.push({
              date: date
            });
          }

          result.schedules.push({
            date: events[i].day,
            time: events[i].time
            //console.log("qua4");
          });
        }
        console.log(result);
        return result;
      }
    };

    return $http.get('http://localhost/ShuttleFIX/api/apiTimes.php', config)
      .then(getEventsCompleted)
      .catch(getEventsFailed);
    function getEventsCompleted(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
      return response.data;
      console.log(response.data);
    }

    function getEventsFailed(error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="list">
                                    <label class="item item-input item-select">
                                        <select ng-options="event as event.date for event in ctrl.data.events" ng-model="ctrl.form.giorno">
                                            <option disabled>Seleziona un giorno </option>
                                        </select>
                                    </label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="list">
                                    <label class="item item-input item-select">
                                        <select ng-options="schedule as schedule.time for schedule in ctrl.data.schedules| filter: { date: ctrl.form.giorno.date}" ng-model="ctrl.form.ora" ng-disabled="!ctrl.form.giorno">
                                            <option disabled>Seleziona un orario </option>
                                        </select>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
```

Another "problem" is that if i creating an html file with  and if i modifie the first line of the js file creating a new module it works.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you highlight the relevant part of the code, instead of providing your whole code?

Comment: i've edited my html code @Mistalis